# google actions: continuous access like a heart beat

Tags: actions-on-google

I have built a google actions project and published it. It has a web hook that is linked to a Google Functions with an actions sdk code behind it. Everything works fine.

However, I have noticed that there is a continuous user (with the same userId provided by the intent) that keeps access the function (guessing via the actions project). I am keeping a kind of sessions log and it keeps creating a session almost every 3-4 seconds.

Since the project is just some temporary demo of content and not really shared with the world at large, I am wondering what or who is causing this continuous access. It looks almost like some heart-beat type of check being done. Hence the question: is it something that Google does to know whether the action project is live or not? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every 3-4 seconds seems high, but if you have published an Action that has gone through the review process Google does run a [health check](https://developers.google.com/actions/console/actions-health-check) against it every few minutes.

Comment: Perfect Prisoner. I will confirm that the request is indeed a health check and take appropriate action (no logging) on my part. Thanks

Comment: To clarify, I was wrong on the frequency of health checks. It seems to be every 6 to 10 mins. And thanks @Prisoner that worked perfectly. I now recognise the health check request and ignore it appropriately.